# Check SSE3 support from bash?

Tags: bash, cpu

Is there a way to check whether or not the current system supports SSE3 from a bash script?

I'm currently writing an installer script, and the program in question has an alternate version that takes advantage of SSE3, and I would like the installer to download that version of the computer's CPU supports SSE3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this might work (PNI implies SSE3):

```
if grep -qE '^flags.* (sse3|pni)' /proc/cpuinfo; then
        echo 'Supported!'
else
        echo 'Not supported!'
fi
```

Comment: I've added an extra space so that grep works on `sse3` but not on `ssse3`